# Exit condition on accumulator in a foreach

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the [connection scan algorithm](http://i11www.iti.uni-karlsruhe.de/extra/publications/dpsw-isftr-13.pdf). Here is one of the steps below that work.

The two `val` in the class are to be refactored but that's not my point. I know I have to refactor the content of the `foreach` but I can't find out how. `earliest` looks like an accumulator so I guess a combination of `fold` and `filter` can be a way... but I get stuck with the exit condition.

```
case class CSA(timetable: Timetable) {
  val inConnection = Array.fill[Int](CSA.MaxStations)(Int.MaxValue)
  val earliestArrival = Array.fill[Int](CSA.MaxStations)(Int.MaxValue)

  private def loop(arrivalStation: Int): Unit = {
    var earliest = Int.MaxValue
    timetable.connections.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (connection, index) =>
      if (connection.conditionOn(earliestArrival)) {
        earliestArrival(connection.arrivalStation) = connection.arrivalTimestamp
        inConnection(connection.arrivalStation) = index
        if (connection.arrivalStation == arrivalStation) {
          earliest = Math.min(earliest, connection.arrivalTimestamp)
        }
      } else if (connection.arrivalTimestamp > earliest) {
        return
      }
    }
  }

  /* other stuff */
}
```

Comment: Usually such algorithms are written as recursion functions (with `@tailrec`) where one case is a stop condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ipoteka already pointed out, this can be accomplished with a recursive function like:

```
def loop(arrivalStation: Int): Unit = {
  var earliest = Int.MaxValue

  @tailrec
  def inner(conns: Stream[(Connection, Int)]): Unit = {
    conns match {
      case Seq() =>
        ()
      case (connection, index) +: tail if connection.arrivalTimestamp > earliest =>
        ()
      case (connection, index) +: tail =>
        if (connection.conditionOn(earliestArrival)) {
          earliestArrival(connection.arrivalStation) = connection.arrivalTimestamp
          inConnection(connection.arrivalStation) = index
          if (connection.arrivalStation == arrivalStation) {
            earliest = Math.min(earliest, connection.arrivalTimestamp)
          }
        }
        inner(tail)
    }
  }
  inner(timetable.connections.zipWithIndex)
}
```